# Proxy to automatically save specific URLs

Tags: automation, proxy

I am looking for a network proxy that would do the following:

If a requested URL matches a certain pattern (regular expressions would be ideal) save the transfer to a specified folder.

I'm not sure if I can achieve that with Squid (that I already have running), but I'm open to using other tools.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hack to accomplish this could be to use
[wwwoffle](http://www.gedanken.demon.co.uk/wwwoffle/): when in
"online" mode, wwwoffle saves all visited pages (excluding those that
match a specified regexp) into a folder.  You can configure the cache
folder path.

As far as I know, there is no direct method to tell WWWOFFLE which
pages/URLs to save, but there could be workarounds to this:

- if you can negate your regexp, you can tell WWWOFFLE which pages
  *not* to save
- if your browser supports the 
  [proxy.pac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) JavaScript-based proxy
  configuration, it's straightforward to cook up a JavaScript
  function that directs the browser to only use the proxy for URLs
  that match a regexp.
- you might be able to configure Squid to use the WWWOFFLE as a parent
  proxy when URL matches a certain pattern; i.e., you have
  browser->Squid->WWWOFFLE->Internet when the request URL matches a
  regexp and browser->Squid->Internet otherwise.

Comment: Looks like a really good option. I'll give it a try next week, see if I can get it to work.